# Extracting text between quotation marks in a specific pattern

Tags: python, python-re

```
string = "'Banana' aaaa 'Melon' aaa 'Strawberry' aaaaa 'Apple' aaaa 'Mango'bbb 'Watermelon' aaaa"
```

What regular expression should I use to get'mango' and'watermelon' on the left and right of bbb among the words enclosed in quotation marks?

```
\'.+?\'
```

All I know is getting the words between the quotes

Comment: what you need is watermelon and mango or words aside bbb?

Comment: 'Mango' <-  bbb  -> 'Watermelon'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `re.findall` twice:

```
string = "'Banana' aaaa 'Melon' aaa 'Strawberry' aaaaa 'Apple' aaaa 'Mango'bbb 'Watermelon' aaaa"
string = re.findall(r"'\S+'\s*bbb\s*'\S+'", string)[0]
matches = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", string)
print(matches)  # ['Mango', 'Watermelon']
```

The first call to `re.findall` isolates the string to just `bbb` with two singly quoted terms on either side.  Then, we make a second call to `re.findall` to extract the quoted terms themselves.